# Navigation zoom in / zoom out not working in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

is it just me or the zoom in and zoom out customized buttons [The ones at the top with the icons that read "Zoom in" and "Zoom out"]do not work?

http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/toolbar_navigation/

[ Regular zooms (the '+' and the '-') do work. ]

I'm currently developing a gis application using arcgis 10.2 javascript api and can't get those buttons to work.

Comment: They work fine for me. Are you drawing an extent box? Try troubleshooting using the debug tools in your browser (usually F12).

Comment: @EokN. Well this is strange. I've tried Arcgis sample with firefox and Firebug shows no error. In chrome, the integrated tool (f12) shows nothing neither.

Comment: Does it fail in all browsers? I've had issues with maps made with the javascript api not working correctly in IE with Compatibility View on.